# Writing the shahada with arabtex

Tags: pdftex, arabic

I'm not familiar with the Arabic alphabet, but would like to write the [shahada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada) in the two ways displayed below using `pdflatex`, for inclusion in a paper.

[image]

How can I do it? Is `arabtex` the way to go?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\begin{document}

\setarab

\begin{arabtext}
% ...
\end{arabtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you not use `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX` and write in unicode?

Comment: @ClintEastwood For my paper I need certain tools that are only available to `pdflatex`, so I fear none of those engines is an option for me.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\begin{document}
\setarab
\fullvocalize
\Huge
\begin{RLtext}
lA 'il_aha 'illA al-ll_ahu mu.hammadaN -rrasuW lu al-ll_ahi
\end{RLtext}
\end{document}

Comment: @kalakay Many thanks! Why not post your comment as an answer? I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\begin{document}
\setarab \fullvocalize \Huge
\begin{RLtext}
lA 'il_aha 'illA al-ll_ahu mu.hammadaN -rrasuW lu al-ll_ahi
\end{RLtext}
\end{document}
```

Anyway, you can see the others [here](http://menulislatex.blogspot.com/2013/12/menulis-huruf-arab-1.html) and [here](http://menulislatex.blogspot.com/2013/12/menulis-huruf-arab-2-contoh-contoh.html).